# StyleCop specific config / MSBuild & Visual Studio various behaviours

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, rules, stylecop

Here is a problem with specific StyleCop configuration.

I've got a total of two Settings.StyleCop files in my Visual Studio .Net solution folders.

The first is placed at the folder root with chosen rules for the team.

As I want to disable some rules for a specific project, I've put another Settings.StyleCop file in the corresponding project folder.

The results are:

- when launching analysis from Visual Studio IDE (Run StyleCop), the project specific file is considered and no violation occurs.
- when launching analysis from StyleCopCmd (command tool) the project specific file seems to be ignored and some violations occur.
- when launching analysis from MSBuild target the project specific file seems also to be ignored and some violations occur.

Did I miss something with StyleCop configuration to have different results from ?

I'm using: Windows XP StyleCop 4.3 MSBuild 3.5 SP1 MSBuild Extension Pack 3.5.0.0 StyleCopCmd 0.2.1.0

The problem seems to be the same with StyleCop 4.3.1.3 and MSBuild Extension Pack 3.5.3.0

Regards,

Olivier.

Comment: Is it possible that your solution-wide/.proj/.targets file for StyleCop may have settings that override your project-specific files?

Comment: It could be possible but wouldn't explain why I get several results. I may test with StyleCop  task (without MSBuild Extension Pack).